# How to update the URL Redirect module v1.4 to its latest version without losing redirects?

Tags: 8, redirection

When I last went to update the URL redirect module from 8.x-1.4 to its latest version I saw this note:

> After 8.x-1.4 version URL Redirect changed as config entity. If you are using before 8.x-1.4 version, it's strongly recommended to not upgrade module as it deletes all existing redirects in your system.

Since I didn't want to lose all my redirects, I just left the module as it was.  Unfortunately, as of yesterday, v8.x-1.4 is no longer supported.

What is the best fix for updating this module?
Is it just a matter of updating to v8.x-2.3 and redoing the redirects (fortunately I do not have a lot of redirects) or is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: I don't see a v2 here for Redirect. https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect

Comment: it isn't the redirect module, but rather the url redirect module https://www.drupal.org/project/url_redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can update module to v8.x-2.3 and run drush updb or update.php. In 8.x-2.3 version all existing redirects get converted to an entity in an update hook.

```
/**
 * Migrate old redirect data.
 */
function url_redirect_update_8103() {

  $db_connection = \Drupal::database();

  if ($db_connection->schema()->tableExists('url_redirect')) {
    $query = $db_connection->select('url_redirect', 'ur');
    $query->fields('ur');
    $all_data = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    foreach ($all_data as $key => $data) {
      $values = array(
          'label' => 'Migrated Redirect',
          'id' => 'migrated_' . $key . '_' . time(),
          'path' => $data->path,
          'redirect_path' => $data->redirect_path,
          'roles' => Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json::decode($data->roles),
          'users' => Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json::decode($data->users),
          'status' => $data->status,
          'message' => $data->message,
          'checked_for' => $data->check_for,
      );
      $url_redirect_entity = \Drupal\url_redirect\Entity\UrlRedirect::create($values);
      $url_redirect_entity->save();
    }

    // We can drop 'url_redirect' table once we confirm everything is migrated properly.
    // $db_connection->schema()->dropTable('url_redirect');
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this mean, handled it in an install file?

Comment: The redirects are now handled within the url_redirect.install file located in the url_redirect folder.  I've edited the original answer to reflect these changes